# UI components are not functional using a MapFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

So I have the following code in a Fragment class trying to show a google Map. Even though the location is detected successfully and is zoomed, all the other UI components (such as the location button) are not shown and the map is somehow not responsive to the gestures. What is the problem?

If I try to call the setupMap() before inflate, the map apparently is not ready and I get a null pointer with getMap.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
              getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.map, mMapFragment);
      fragmentTransaction.commit();

      View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.afragment, container, false);

      setupMap();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;
    }
```

And I set up my Map with the following:

```
private void setupMap(){
         if (mMap == null) {
             mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                                 .getMap();
             // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
             if (mMap != null) {
                //Set Location etc
                             ........

                mMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);

                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

              // Zoom in the Google Map
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));

                mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);

             }
         }          
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use MapView....

See https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551

I didn't want to change the api version and exclude other devices (as suggested by MaciejGórski), but I believe that answer is also useful indicating the problem with nested fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `Fragment` inside another `Fragment` is tricky.

Try this code instead: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5064#c1

Make sure you use [`Fragment.getChildFragmentManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager%28%29). If you are developing for API lower than 17 (Android 4.2), you have to switch to support library.

Also read this: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments